# Null data is received from angulajs to MVC controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Dears, I have two classes Master and detail named by Raterequest and Raterequestdetails. I have created a viewmodel contains both of them. in Angularjs i have an object contains rate and a list contains orderdetails. when i debug the controller the data received is null for both here is the code

Rate request class

```
    public class RateRequests
{
    public int RateRequestsID { get; set; }
    public DateTime RateRequestsDate { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestName { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestType { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestMode { get; set; }
}
```

Rate request details class

```
 public class RateRequestsLines
{
    public int RateRequestsLinesID { get; set; }
    public int RateRequestsID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RateRequestsID")]
    public virtual RateRequests RateRequestsFK { get; set; }
    public short FCLCNTRS { get; set; }
    public short FCLCNTRSSIZE { get; set; }
    public string FCLCNTRSTYPE { get; set; }

}
```

Rate request view model

```
 public class RateRequestViewModel
{
    public RateRequests rate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RateRequestsLines> ratelines { get; set; }
}
```

Angularjs

```
    var linkers = angular.module("linkers", [])
.service("linkersSrv", function ($http) {

    var urlBase = "/LinkersEgypt/";

    this.save = function (url, ratee) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: urlBase + "/" + url,
            data: ratee,
            ̶a̶s̶y̶n̶c̶:̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶,̶
        })

    };

})
.controller("linkersCon", function ($scope, linkersSrv) {

    $scope.fcl = [];

    $scope.addFCL = function () {
        $scope.fcl.push({ FCLCNTRS: $scope.ncntrs, FCLCNTRSSIZE: $scope.csize, FCLCNTRSTYPE: $scope.ctype });
        console.log($scope.fcl);
    }

    $scope.save = function () {

        var ratee = {
            rate: {
                RateRequestsDate: $scope.rdate,
                RateRequestName: $scope.rname,
                RateRequestType: $scope.rtype,
                RateRequestMode: $scope.smode
            },
            RateRequestsLines: $scope.fcl
        };

        console.log(ratee);
        var promisepost = linkersSrv.save("RateRequest/AddAllRate", ratee);
        promisepost.then(function () {
            toastr.success("Successfully saved");

        })

    }
})
```

Rate controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddAllRate (RateRequestViewModel rate)
{
    return new JsonResult();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you data do not match. Try removing some fields from angular object and your view model in order to match and the n try adding one by one back

Comment: ok i will try then notify

Comment: still the data null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public RateRequests()
    {
        this.ratelines = new HashSet<RateRequestsLines>();
    }

    public int RateRequestsID { get; set; }
    public DateTime RateRequestsDate { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestName { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestType { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestMode { get; set; }


    public ICollection<RateRequestsLines> ratelines { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddAllRate (RateRequestViewModel mainrate)
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var raterequest = new RateRequests()
                {
                    RateRequestMode = mainrate.rate.RateRequestMode,
                    RateRequestName = mainrate.rate.RateRequestName,
                    RateRequestsDate = mainrate.rate.RateRequestsDate,
                    RateRequestType = mainrate.rate.RateRequestType,

                };

                foreach (var i in mainrate.ratelines)
                {
                    raterequest.ratelines.Add(i);
                }

                db.raterequests.Add(raterequest);
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```